# Get type of generic list

Tags: c#, generics

In code listed bellow I need determine type of TSource. Parsed parameter can be, for example IList, or only Car etc. In method Model.Map<> I need parse type of generic type. Everything works fine when parsed parameter is single object (Car, Boat...). Problem is when collection is parsed. So, I need to cover case when parameter is collection.

```
public class Convert<TSource, TDestination>
{
    public static TDestination ToModel(TSource source)
    {
        Model.Map<TSource, TDestination>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've given is currently invalid - you're trying to pass `TSource` as an argument. Are you just looking for `typeof(TSource)`?

Comment: Typeof(TSource) doesn't works.

Comment: I think it's not only when `TSource` is a Collection, it also becomes complicated when `TSource` is any generic type such as  `MyClass<MyClass<MyClass>>` for example. What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: @GameScripting - Correct. It can be any type (include generic type). I can call method with prameter IList<Car>, or only Car. But, I need to parse only underlying type (in example with collection that is Car).

Convert<IList<Car>, IList<Boat>>.ToModel(carsList);
Convert<Car, Boat>.ToModel(carsList);

So, In model method I need to determine when type of generic in the case when collection is parsed.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with - based on `GetGenericArguments`

```
var type = source.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx

Comment: Hmm...I don't understand you.

Comment: SilverDeveloper GetGenericArguments return your generic type on index equals to 0 in your array, because your generic can contains array of type, here you get your first item type

Answer (score 0):

Try [System.Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)